# How can I determine variogram model in R using R-squared?

Tags: r

I made a code to drawing variogram.
I want to know which variogram model is best fitting.
So I want to calculate R-Squared.
How can I determine variogram model in R using R-squared?

this is data link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B58l7t8QjmcnTlNFcnYweEpBSnM/view?usp=sharing

---

```
library(sp)
library(gstat)
library(rgdal)

jeju<-read.csv('C:/Program Files/R/Input_jeju.csv')
jeju<-na.omit(jeju)

coordinates(jeju)<-~LONG+LAT
proj4string(jeju) =  "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"
jeju<-spTransform(jeju, CRS("+proj=utm +north +zone=52 +datum=WGS84"))

jeju.var<-variogram(log(OUT)~1,data=jeju,cutoff=80000, width=8000)
jeju.var

plot(jeju.var)

s1 <- vgm(psill=1.2,model="Sph",range=18000,nugget=0.04)
e1 <- vgm(psill=1.2,model="Exp",range=18000,nugget=0.04)
g1 <- vgm(psill=1.2,model="Gau",range=18000,nugget=0.04)

s1a<- fit.variogram(jeju.var,s1)
e1a<- fit.variogram(jeju.var,e1)
g1a<- fit.variogram(jeju.var,g1)

s1a
e1a
g1a

plot(jeju.var,s1a)
plot(jeju.var,e1a)
plot(jeju.var,g1a)
```